# Convexity Proof for $\mathbb R ^n \backslash A$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

I need to tell if it is true or false and prove that given $A$ a convex set, $\mathbb R^n$ \ $ A $ is never convex.

So far I get that considering $p,q \in \mathbb R^n$ convex, $\lambda p + (1- \lambda)q \in \mathbb R^n$, and removing $A$ from it will make no difference if $p,q$ aren't part of the set $A$. Is it enough?

Comment: I hope you don't *really* need it, because the claim is false.

Comment: Actually, the exercise asks if it is true or false and to prove it. I just edited the question.

Comment: Well, now you have a clue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @dantopa my first post so figuring out how to make use of it. Added all my thoughts until now.

Comment: Consider $A$ to be a half-space.

Answer (score 1):

The straight line divides the plane into two complementary convex sets. In general, the same holds for a hyperplane.